# Determine search results based on user location

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a simple google-scraping tool. How it works is like this:

1. The user will first enter their location, say Canada (or even cities)
2. The user will perform the search, say 'Thai restaurant'
3. The tool must be able to return the search results indicating all the  'Thai restaurants' in Canada. This result must be a google search result. Meaning whatever search result it returns, the restaurant in the url must be based in Canada and not anywhere else

Currently, I have the number 2 working. Which means I can perform google-search for a particular keyword and it returns all the results *(not focused on location)*

I was wondering if there is a way to only perform a localised search.
'I want to know what Thai restaurants are there in Canada'. This will output a bunch of uURLsthat are 'located' in Canada.

Comment: there is a google api that allows you to do that. check [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Comment: Yes, I know about that but is there a way to not do it using Google Places API?